# How to solve these types of permutation problems?

Tags: probability

One thing I observe that, the way we calculate $nPn$, doesn't actually work for the cases of $nPr$.

(1) How many permutations are possible if we take 3 letters at a time from the list {A,A,B,C,E} where the words always start with an A and ends with an A?
Ans:  $\frac{^{5-2}P_{3-2}}{2!} = 3$ .

(2) How many permutations are possible if we take 3 letters at a time from the list {A,A,B,C,E} where the words always start with an AA?
Ans:  $\frac{^{5-2}P_{3-2}}{2!} = 3$ .

(3) How many permutations are possible if we take 3 letters at a time from the list {A,A,B,C,E} where the words always start with an A?
Ans:  $^{5-1}P_{3-1} = 12$ .

(4) How many of them contain AA?
Answer: 3P2 = 6.

(5) How many permutations are possible if we take 3 letters at a time from the list {A,A,B,C,E} where the words always start with an E?
Ans:

The answer should be 7.

But, $^{5-1}P_{3-1} = 12$ is wrong.

(6) How many of them start with a vowel?
Ans:

The answer should be 19.

But, $^{5-3}P_{3-3} = 2$ is wrong.

My question is, which problems should I solve by using multiplications between different permuted values, which questions should I solve by using additions between different permuted values, and, which problems should I solve by hand-counting (ie. Permutation formula doesn't work)?

Another question is, how should I deal with overcounting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using intuition and not formulae**

I would try to use common sense first in solving counting problems. Whether it is a permutation or a combination is just incidental.

To take your example, **Question (5)**. The 3-letter word starts with $E$. Now there are $3$ cases on the other 2 letters (a) No $A$ is used ... $\color{blue}{2}$ arrangements (b) Exactly one $A$ is used ... $\color{blue}{4}$ arrangements and (c) Both $A$'s are used ... $\color{blue}{1}$ arrangement. So the total is $2 + 4 + 1 = \color{blue}{7}$ arrangements. Here the question of using a formula did not even arise.

**Question (6)**.  We want vowel first, so there are $2$ cases (a) The word starts with $A$. which leaves us $\{A, B, C, E \}$ to choose 2 letters, that is $4P2$ which is $\color{blue}{12}$ ways and (b) The word starts with $E$ which leaves us $\{A, A, B, C \}$ to choose 2 letters. The repetition of the A's is dealt similarly as in Question (5) and we will get $1 + 6 = \color{blue}{7}$ ways. Hence you get $12 + 7 = \color{blue}{19}$ as your answer.

On your question of not double counting, once you start using common sense reasoning and not just formulae, you will probably be pretty safe.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to 5 th is 7 . See  we have to select three lettets where first letter E is fixed. Now  from  4 letters we have to select two so we have  4C1 but A is common so divided by 2 and next letter can be selected in 3C1 ways . So answer is 1+(4C1/2.3C1)=7. Note  the difference between permutation and combination. Combination is selection of n things taken r at a time while permutation is arrangement of distinct things taken r at a time.

Comment: You are solving a permutation problem by using Combination. Why? Please, clarify in your main answer body.

Comment: If u want I can clarify you on that May I??

Comment: I am giving an example here.Combination  is selecting a team of r football players from n players . But permutation  is arranging the squad of these football players under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing the most restrictive elements you can, then identify a subproblem to solve.

E.g. to count the permutations of the alphabet that starts with A and ends with Z, I know I must place A and Z at either end, so the answer will be the ways to permute the 24 remaining letters in the middle, $24!$.

One way strategy might be to count the ways you can construct a new set for which the direct permutation calculation can be applied.

E.g. to count the 4-permutations of $\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$ that contain a $1$ and a $4$, form a new set by picking $1$ and $4$ and 2 other elements. For this new set there are $4!$ permutations. But there were $^4C_2$ ways to choose those extra elements, so the answer is $4! \times ^4C_2$.

**Edit:**

(when I say n-permutation I mean a permutation of the set containing n items. I *think* this is standard terminology)

E.g. find 5-permutations of $\left\{1,1,1,2,3,4\right\}$ that have 3 $1$s next to each other. As before: deal with the difficult stuff first. As we have to have the $1$s next to each other, think of them as a single element. So now the problem becomes "find the 3-permutations of $\left\{\left\{1,1,1\right\},2,3,4\right\}$ that contains the $\left\{1,1,1\right\}$". Dealing with the difficult stuff first, we know we must include the $1$s. Form a new set by choosing the $1$s and 2 other elements. There are $3!$ ways to permute this new set. But there were $^3C_2$ ways to choose those extra elements, so the answer is $3! \times ^3C_2$.

When the set contains multiple copies of an element (a *multiset*) the reasoning that gives the $^nP_r$ formula no longer holds. Some permutations may contain several copies of an element and so are overcounted, some aren't. You can transform the problem into something more familiar as I have above, or perhaps count the cases of overcounting separately, adjust for it, then add up your separate cases.

E.g. find the 3-permutations of $\left\{A,A,B,C,D\right\}$. Counting the permutations with 2 $A$s, there are $^3C_1 = 3$ ways to choose the 3rd element after being forced to choose the 2 $A$s. There are $3!$ ways to permute this new set. But we have counted each permutation twice, so divide by $2$, = $\frac{3 \times 3!}{2} = 9$. With just 1 $A$, there are $^3C_2 = 3$ ways to choose the remaining 2 elements, and $3!$ ways to permute, with no overcounting this comes to $3 \times 3! = 18$. With no $A$s there are $^3C_3 = 1$ way to choose the 3 elements, with $3!$ permutations, with no overcounting this is $6$ permutations. So the answer is $9 + 18 + 6 = 33$.

Comment: Here, the crux of the problem is, the duplication of A. There are two A's in the list. That made the whole calculation complicated. Please, shed some light on that. And, secondly, You are solving a permutation problem by using Combination. Why? Please, clarify in your main answer body.

Comment: @anonymous I'll edit my answer with an example of that. Regarding the combination use: don't think that because you are asked for permutations you are restricted to using certain methods. Use the best tool for the job, i.e. what works and what is clearest. Do you understand the reasoning? - this is the important question.